# How to display API data in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, jsondecoder

I am making an app for myself that shows a comment feed for a subreddit and I am trying to display the user flairs. There are two ways to display user flairs from Reddit, one is to use the `author_flair_text` property which returns a string where emojis are represented by their names such as `This is my flair :emoji:` and the other one is to user the `author_flair_richtext` property with returns a value such as the following:

```
"author_flair_richtext": [
            {
              "a": ":emojiName:",
              "e": "emoji",
              "u": "link to the image for that emoji"
            },
            {
              "e": "text",
              "t": " Flair text"
            }
          ]
```

I aam doing all of this in SwiftUI and here is my code so far:

```
struct FlairComponent: Decodable {
    var a: String?
    var e: String?
    var u: String?
    var t: String?
}

struct Comment: Decodable, Identifiable {
    //Other properties
    var author_flair_richtext: [FlairComponent?]
}
```

Then I want to do something along the lines of this, but this won't work and I'm not entirely sure why because I'm new to this but my best guess is that not messes with the opaque return type by having optional views.

```
struct CommentFeedView: View {
    @State var comments = [Comment]()
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(comments) { comment in
            if let flairComponents = comment.author_flair_richtext {
                 ForEach(flairComponents) { flairComponent in
                      if let emojiURLString = flairComponent.u {
                           Image(UIImage: getEmojiUIImage(for: emojiURLString))
                      } else if let emojiText = flairComponent.t{
                           Text(emojiText)
                      }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, any tips on how to implement the getEmojiImage(for:) function are appreciated immensely! Please have a good day or night and thank you for reading this far :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, different types come to you in field `e`, and if this is an `emoji`, you need to get it. Is it right?
For this, it is always better to create a separate view that will do this. Let it be a `DisplayFlairView`, in which there will be a variable `richText` - is an array of `FlairComponent`. Now, in the body, we will check if there is rich text, and if so, we will create a HStack with components, checking that it is text or emoji. also, for obtaining images, I recommend URLImage - a very good library that is well suited for caching many images at once. Example code

```
struct DisplayFlairView: View {
    
    let richText: [FlairComponent]?
    
    var body: some View {
        if let flairText = richText {
            HStack(spacing: 4) {
                ForEach(flairText, id: \.self) { oneFlair in
                    if oneFlair.e == "emoji" {
                        URLImage(url: oneFlair.u!) { image in
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        }
                    } else if oneFlair.e == "text" {
                        Text(oneFlair.t!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And using in your comment is

```
struct CommentFeedView: View {
    @State var comments = [Comment]()
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(comments) { comment in
            if let flairComponents = comment.author_flair_richtext, !flairComponents.isEmpty {
                 DisplayFlairView(richText: flairComponents)
            }
        }
    }
}
```